# Pass from JQuery to React JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I've a problem with an example of JQuery, is this:

```
$('.popUp').on('click', function() {
   openWindow(this.href);
   return false;
});
```

How to can pass this to Javascript?
I trying, this:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.popUp')
elements.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   openWindow(this.ref);
   return false;
}))
```

This works for me, but I think this is not optimal

Comment: That's how it's done with vanilla javascript, why do you think it's not right? I would only change to use `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`. Also, this has nothing to do with React.

Comment: @arieljuod, there is react here, although it's kind of hard to spot. David's problem is most likely caused by the `this` binding being different in the two function types he's using.

Comment: @edo.n he said that's working properly, there no error related to `this` (though I would use `event.target.href` to get the href of the clicked element)

Comment: The purpose of posting this question was to see if maybe there was a better way to create this logic, thanks for the comments